# Trouble getting a login with PHP to take input

Tags: php, database, authentication

***the question has been answered. Here is the solution:

Ok, so I need to address a few things before answering the problem. First, the database is meant to have the numerous security flaws. This is a security class, and I am trying to hack into it on purpose. Then after I hack in, i'm supposed to prevent my own attacks.

Second thing I wish to clear up, is that this is a local database only, and never used by anyone but myself, classmates and instructor.

now for the answer: The first thing I was doing wrong was that the code was supposed to be logged into from the localhost webpage. I was trying to log in from the login.php file.

Second thing, was that I was mixing my mysql * and mysqli * methods. You cannot have multiple versions of the same method in the code.

Thanks to all who posted and for the fast responses.

A brief explanation of the problem: 
I have been coding a database for a school project. I have the school database set up correctly, as per the instructor's review. The code I have is supposed to take a user input, check it with a "enrolled" list of students and compare the student ID and passsword to a pre-existing list. 
After the check, the code is to start a session based on the student being enrolled. If the student is not enrolled it redirects them to the login page again.

The trouble I am having is that the code simply doesn't work. I get a error that says I have an issue on line 35 of my login.php file. Here is my code:

```
<?php
//Connect to DB
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","cravenreach","univ");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else 
{
    echo "Succeed to connect to MySQL. ";
}
//Session setup
session_start();
if( isset($_POST['sid']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
$checklogin = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM students WHERE sid=".$_POST['sid']." AND password=".$_POST['password']);
 echo $count1 = mysql_num_rows($checklogin);
 if($count1==1)
{
    // auth okay, setup session
    $_SESSION['sid'] = $_POST['sid'];
    // redirect to required page
    header( "Location: main.php" );
 } 
 else {
    // didn't auth go back to login
   header( "Location: login.php" );
 }
 }
else {
 // username and password not given so go back to login
//header( "Location: login.php" ); 
//This code is broken, causes a redirect loop.
echo "failure to start";
//header( "location: .php");
 }

?>
```

here is the index.php code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<p><label>Student ID: <input type="text" name="sid"></label></p>
<p><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"></label></p>
<input type="submit">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I receive is this: "Succeed to connect to MySQL. failure to start."
I understand that the code is not evaluating the login as true, and is skipping down to the last else statement. I just dont understand why.

To recap: My code will not actually accept the correct student input (or incorrect for that matter) and will not allow the user to login. It simply throws an error. My question is: what is wrong with my code? Is my query wrong, or implementation of the session?

Comment: Can you try a `var_dump($_POST)` in your login.php code? It'll show you whether your fields are being sent successfully or not.

Comment: First: Your school project is horribly wrong, and has extremely big security "holes". The most primitive security things have been broken here. Even I could take over your server in under 10seconds. Your prof/teacher should really take some dev lessons!

Comment: For one thing, you're mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` functions, so that will put a damper on things.

Comment: @andrewsi
I never get to input anything. I get the error before I can input data. It's almost like it is not going to the index page first.

Comment: True. Plus the OP's code has too many errors. Just afraid that putting in an actual answer will open up a proverbial "can of worms". @Jerry

Comment: @ZacharyStewart - are you opening index.php? Because there's nothing in the code there that would move you on to login.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `mysql_*` functions into `mysqli_*` and also, You need add `"` end of the query before `)`

```
$checklogin = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM students WHERE sid='".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['sid'])."' AND password='".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."' ");
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. 
I changed all of the mysql functions into the mysquli as suggested.

Comment: Did you submitted  the form, `$_POST['sid']` and `$_POST['password']` are not set thats why you getting the failure to start from your code

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like

```
//Prevnt from SQL injection
$sid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sid']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE sid='$sid' AND password='$password'",$con);
```

Note MySQL is deprecated use MySQLi or PDO

Comment: I tried making the change that you suggested, but the code still outputs to the same error. 
Thanks for the input BTW.